# Add Mobclix to Cocos2d Scene

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Has anyone integrating mobclix into a cocos2d application? I tried to add a banner of Ad by using Mobclix, but it did not appear, my code:

```
//In appDelegate:
[Mobclix startWithApplicationId:@"4778FFA3-DDFF-4550-BFFE-7B7AB4B5765D"];
[Mobclix start]; 

//In my Scene
-(void)onEnter {

    adView = [MobclixAdViewiPhone_320x50 new];
    adView.delegate = self; //Optional

    // set position
   adView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 320, 50);
   dView.refreshTime = 15;

    // add to view
   [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:adView];

   // set refresh (automatically gets one ad when changing the property)
   [adView getAd];

   [super onEnter];
```

Anyone help me to show Adbanner on my Scene please?